# People Picker and FBA - partial functionality

Tags: forms-authentication, people-picker, membership-provider

So I've read a number of other questions on this topic and believe my situation is different.  I have a web application with Forms Authentication.  It is configured in the web.config files of central admin, the web app, and the security token service.  I have the wildcards configured for the membership provider in central admin and the web application.

When I open a document library on the web application (as a fba user), the Key Filters for Created By and Modified By come back with the following error:

No exact match was found. Click the item(s) that did not resolve for more options.

If I type in a partial value it gives me legitimate suggestions, but if I select one I still get the error message and the Key filter does not actually filter anything

Web Application:

```
<PeoplePickerWildcards>
  <clear />
  <add key="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" value="%" />
  <add key="MY-MembershipProvider" value="%" />
</PeoplePickerWildcards>
<membership defaultProvider="i">
  <providers>
    <add name="i" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <!--connection string for GCS Customer sql membership authentication with sharepoint-->
    <add connectionStringName="MYMembership" passwordAttemptWindow="5" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="MIRHostedSolution" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" description="Stores and Retrieves membership data from SQL Server" name="MY-MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="c" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
  <providers>
    <add name="c" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <!--connection string for GCS Customer sql membership authentication with sharepoint-->
    <add connectionStringName="MYMembership" applicationName="MIRHostedSolution" description="Stores and retrieves roles from SQL Server" name="MY-RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Central Admin

```
<PeoplePickerWildcards>
  <clear />
  <add key="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" value="%" />
  <add key="MY-MembershipProvider" value="%" />
</PeoplePickerWildcards>
<roleManager defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="SQLConnectionString" applicationName="gcsapplication" description="Stores and retrieves roles from SQL Server" name="SQL-RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <!-- Role manager provider for GCS Customer -->
    <add connectionStringName="GcsCustomerDbConnectionString" applicationName="MIRHostedSolution" description="Stores and retrieves roles from SQL Server" name="GCS-RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <!-- Role manager provider for GCS Customer -->
    <add connectionStringName="GcsMIRForMembership" applicationName="MIRHostedSolution" description="Stores and retrieves roles from SQL Server" name="GCSMIR-RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <add connectionStringName="MYMembership" applicationName="MIRHostedSolution" description="Stores and retrieves roles from SQL Server" name="MY-RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="SQL-MembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="SQLConnectionString" passwordAttemptWindow="5" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="gcsapplication" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" description="Stores and Retrieves membership data from SQL Server" name="SQL-MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <!-- Membership  provider for GCS Customer -->
    <add connectionStringName="GcsCustomerDbConnectionString" passwordAttemptWindow="5" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="MIRHostedSolution" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" description="Stores and Retrieves membership data from SQL Server" name="GCS-MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <!-- Membership  provider for GCS Customer -->
    <add connectionStringName="GcsMIRForMembership" passwordAttemptWindow="5" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="MIRHostedSolution" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" description="Stores and Retrieves membership data from SQL Server" name="GCSMIR-MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <add connectionStringName="MYMembership" passwordAttemptWindow="5" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="MIRHostedSolution" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" description="Stores and Retrieves membership data from SQL Server" name="MY-MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

STS Config

```
<membership defaultProvider="i"> 
    <providers> 
        <add name="i" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" /> 
        <add connectionStringName="SQLConnectionString" passwordAttemptWindow="5" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="gcsapplication" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" description="Stores and Retrieves membership data from SQL Server" name="SQL-MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />


    <add connectionStringName="MYMembership" passwordAttemptWindow="5" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="MIRHostedSolution" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" description="Stores and Retrieves membership data from SQL Server" name="MY-MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </providers> 
</membership> 

  <system.web>      
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <remove name="HttpGet" />
                <remove name="HttpPost" />
                <remove name="HttpPostLocalhost" />
                <add name="Documentation" />
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <customErrors mode="On"/>
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <identity impersonate="false" />
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the STS config which needs to be done on each server in the farm.  Also, CA should not have a default provider.  While [these are AD LDS examples](http://sharepoint.nauplius.net/2012/11/sharepoint-2010-and-2013-sample-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services-configuration-files/), it should get you pointed in the right direction for overall configuration.

Comment: see update.  The STS configuration was already there, and removing default provider from CA config did not change anything regarding functionality.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's a reason those examples used * instead of % for the wildcard?

Comment: The wildcard for SQL is "%", the wildcard for LDAP is "*".

Comment: none of that has actually worked for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you update with the entire membership/role provider sections of your WebApp/CA and the entire <system.web> section in the STS?

Comment: Yes I can, I will do this later today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this turned out to be a database permission issue.  Apparently the special database roles that come along with the generated ASP.NET membership framework-generated databases are required for all users who wish to do things with the membership database.  Farm account has dbo, so that's not a problem and that's why the thing works in Central Administration.  However, the app pool account for the web application only had data reader (which I thought should be PLENTY of permission).  I must have switched the app pool account from being the same as the farm account (dev server, etc) at some point which would be why I started encountering these issues.

[This is the guide I used which explicitly mentioned these permissions.](http://blog.morg.nl/2011/08/step-by-step-forms-based-authentication-fba-on-sharepoint-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Matt, I discovered that this was a permissions issue. I have a `SharePointServerFarm` account that runs the application pools and other various SharePoint services.

I mapped this user to my forms database, and gave it the db_owner role. This fixed the issue.